# How does the command key in docker-compose file work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to understand the docker sample application 'example-voting-app'. I am trying to build the app with docker-compose. I am confused with the behaviour of 'command' key in docker compose file and the CMD Instruction in Dockerfile. The application consists of a service called 'vote'. The configuration for the vote service in docker-compose.yml file is:

```
services: # we list all our application services under this 'services' section.
  vote:  
    build: ./vote # specifies docker to build the 
    command: python app.py
    volumes:
     - ./vote:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
```

The configuration of the Dockerfile provided in ./vote directory is as below:

```
# Using official python runtime base image
FROM python:2.7-alpine

# Set the application directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install our requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy our code from the current folder to /app inside the container
ADD . /app

# Make port 80 available for links and/or publish
EXPOSE 80

# Define our command to be run when launching the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80", "--log-file", "-", "--access-logfile", "-", "--workers", "4", "--keep-alive", "0"]
```

My doubt here is which command ( 'python app.py' or 'gunicorn app:app -b ...') will be executed when i try building the application using docker-compose up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Docker Compose `command:`, or everything in a `docker run` invocation after the image name, overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`.

If the image also has an `ENTRYPOINT`, the command you provide here is [passed as arguments to the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the same way the Dockerfile `CMD` does.

For a typical Compose setup you shouldn't need to specify a `command:`.  In a Python/Flask context, the most obvious place it's useful is if you're also using a queueing system like Celery with the same shared code base: you can use `command:` to run a Celery worker off of the image you build, instead of a Flask application.